# Reset MCU with a 1-0 button

Tags: microcontroller, reset, 8051, sleep

I am working on a silabs C8051 MCU. It has a sleep mode which should be woken up by  a reset. The mcu should start working (wake up from sleep) when the button in connected to Ground (Otherwise it is on the air). What is the easiest way to give a reset signal to the reset pin (or any other way) to restart the MCU?

Comment: ...a pcb trace?

Comment: define `easiest` .... also, what does this mean? `Otherwise it is on the air`

Answer (score 2):

You usually pull the reset pin for 2 machine cycles to reset the 8051 Microcontroller. You could do that easily using a push button, as per the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJE8sz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This would straight away, work.

But if you wish to have a better more universal reset button, you could follow the following schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUF1dw.png)</sup>

Both will do the job.